# Create range from column

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I have a list of positions:

```
pos
123
100024
1025
5426
```

I want to define a range of these positions

E.g.

100-1000

1001-2500

etc...

So when i do a Select of how many positions there are in that range counts the number of elements in the range.

I've tried with:

```
SELECT pos , generate_seres(max(pos)::int, min(pos)::int, 1000::int) 
as pos_int
FROM varianti
group by pos 
ORDER BY pos;
```

But i don't think that is correct...

Is there a way?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and found to not work?

Comment: Sure, i was editing in fact adding the info you requested.

Comment: Why doesn't the first range start with `0`?

Comment: The range starts from the min(pos), but it can also starts from 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first range is allowed to start with `0`, you can do something like this:

```
with ranges (range) as (
  select int4range(i, i + 1000, '[)')
  from generate_series(0, (select max(pos) from varianti), 1000) as i
) 
select range,
       count(v.pos) as range_count
from ranges l
  left join varianti v 
         on v.pos <@ l.range
group by range
order by range;
```

For this data:

```
insert into varianti (pos)
values
(123), (150), (170), 
(1025), (1050), (1051), (1052), (1053), (1054), (1054), 
(2054), (2051), 
(3001), (3002), (3003), (3004), (4004), 
(5426);
```

This returns:

```
range       | range_count
------------+------------
[0,1000)    |           3
[1000,2000) |           7
[2000,3000) |           2
[3000,4000) |           4
[4000,5000) |           1
[5000,6000) |           1
```